# Reference for diagonalization theorems

Tags: matrices, reference-request, matrix-decomposition

I know there is a theorem as follows:
If A is a real symmetric matrix, then A is orthogonally
diagonalizable; in other words, there exists an orthogonal matrix P (i.e. a real matrix satisfying $P^{-1} = P^T$ such that $P^{-1} A P$ is a diagonal matrix.

And I know how we can prove it. But I need a reference book having this theorem to which I can refer because I cannot reprove it in my paper. I just want to use it. I appreciate if anybody can introduce a reference for this to me.

Thanks

Comment: This is theorem 23.16 (p. 621) in Simon & Blume's "Mathematics for Economists".

Comment: @NigelOvermars Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Horn and Johnson (2013 edition), theorem 2.5.3 on page 133.

Comment: A summary would be nice.

Comment: @vonbrand A summary of the theorem?  OP provided it.  A summary of the proof?  That's not what's being asked for. If you're interested in seeing a proof, perhaps you should post your own question.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that theorem is not specifically about real symmetric.

Comment: Well, it does even more than you need. In any case, you might also want to try Friedberg, Insel, Spence.